# Vista UAC Issues with samba and Admin Credentials

Tags: samba

We have Samba setup for our shared drive. I have pasted the smb.conf file below. Everything is working well accept when we try and run an EXE file using Windows Vista. When we run an EXE file it first ask for UAC control then it pops up the username and password prompt. You must then type your username and password in again before it will run.

I think the issues is that UAC is now running the application under Admin instead of the logged in user. So the first username and password that is cached is not seen by the admin user. Does anyone know of a work around for this?

```
smb.conf:
[global]

passdb backend = tdbsam

security = user
encrypt passwords = yes

preferred master = Yes

workgroup = Workgroup
netbios name = Omni
bind interfaces only = True
interfaces = lo eth2

;max disk size = 990000   ;some programs (like PS7) can't deal with more than 1TB 

socket options = TCP_NODELAY
server string = Omni
;smb ports = 139

debuglevel = 1
syslog = 0
log level = 2
log file = /var/log/samba/%U.log
max log size = 61440

vfs objects = omnidrive recycle

recycle:repository = RecycleBin/%U
recycle:keeptree = Yes
recycle:touch = No
recycle:versions = Yes
recycle:maxsize = 0
recycle:exclude = *.temp *.mp3 *.cat 
omnidrive:log = 2
omnidrive:com_log = 1
omnidrive:vscan = 1
omnidrive:versioningState = 1
omnidrive:versioningMaxFileSize = 0
omnidrive:versioningMaxRevSize = 7168
omnidrive:versioningMaxRevNum = 1000
omnidrive:versioningMinRevNum = 0 
omnidrive:versioningfilesInclude = /*.doc/*.docx/*.xls/*.xlsx/*.txt/*.bmp/
omnidrive:versioningfilesExclude = /*.tmp/*.temp/*.exe/*.com/*.jarr/*.bat/.*/

full_audit:failure = none
full_audit:success = mkdir rename unlink rmdir write open close
full_audit:prefix = %u|%I|%m|%S
full_audit:priority = NOTICE
full_audit:facility = LOCAL6

;dont descend = RecycleBin

veto files = /.subversion/*.do/*.do/*.bar/*.cat/

client ntlmv2 auth = yes

[netlogon]
path = /var/lib/samba/netlogon
read only = yes

[homes]
read only = yes
browseable = no

[share1]
path = /share1
read only = no
browseable = yes
writable = yes
admin users = clinton1 
public = no
create mask = 0770
directory mask = 0770
nt acl support = no
;acl map full control = no
hide unreadable = yes
store dos attributes = yes
map archive = no
map readonly = Permissions
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone cares; this is how I fixed the issues on vista:

I set a key to link the UAC account and the none UAC account.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
EnableLinkedConnections =(dword)1

The password prompt goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can also address this by turning off UAC in Vista or Windows 7.  Here's a link for doing that: [Turn User Account Control on or off](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Turn-User-Account-Control-on-or-off)